# Reality Composer: How to replace object without losing behaviours?

Tags: augmented-reality, reality-composer, reality-converter

I have a 3D model which I'm setting up for AR using Reality Composer on a Mac. I've assigned a few basic behaviours to the model. For example, making certain objects spin when tapped.

The problem: I will need to make changes to the model based on client requests. When I make the changes and import the new model into Reality Composer the behaviours seem to be "unlinked". I'm hoping there's a way to import an updated model without having to set up the behaviours every time.

I'm new to Reality Composer so I might be missing something obvious.

I tried using the built-in "replace" option in the right-click menu. This does replace the model, but not without breaking the behaviours.